# Series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^k}{n!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there a formula for $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^k}{n!}$ in terms of $k$?

What about  $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n-1)^k}{n!}$?

Comment: I believe you have checked convergence....

Comment: Yes, it converges..

Answer (score 7):

They are of the form $B_ke$, where $B_k$ is a [Bell number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number). They represent the number of partitions of a set with *n* members, as well as the coefficients of the [Taylor series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) for $e^{e^x}$. See [Dobinski's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dobinski%27s_formula), whose proof can be found [here](http://www.archive.org/stream/archivdermathem88unkngoog#page/n345/mode/2up). Their sequence is on [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A000110), and their values can be computed using a formula similar to that of Pascal's [triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_triangle). As for your second sum, it is of the form $N_ke-$$(-1)^k$ where $N_k$ represent the number of partitions of a set of *n* elements into blocks of size greater than $1$ Their sequence, along with additional explanations as to their other meanings, can also be found on [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A000296).