# Special functions related to $\sum\limits _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{x^n \log (n!)}{n!}$

Tags: special-functions, entropy

While doing some caculation related to von Neumann entropy, I encountered this kind of convergent series. 
$$\text{Exl}(x) \equiv \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{x^n \log (n!)}{n!}$$
In my calculation, this function Exl$(x)$ appears in some places where exponential function should be, for example,
$$\frac{\cosh (x) \text{Cxl}(x) + \sinh (x)\text{Sxl}(x)}{\cosh(2x)}$$ 
appears in my calculation, where
$$\text{Cxl}(x) \equiv \frac{\text{Exl} (x) +\text{Exl} (-x)}{2}$$
and
$$\text{Sxl}(x) \equiv \frac{\text{Exl} (x) -\text{Exl} (-x)}{2}$$
are defined from the similarity to the hyperbolic functions. 
As the given function Exl$(x)$ looks like some kind of 'augmented' exponential function as the following plot suggests,
[image]

I suspect there's a well defined special function related to this series. Is it so? Any kind of suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: For large $x$, $\operatorname{Exl}(x)$ is larger than $e^x$ by a factor of roughly $x\log(x)$. Specifically, $\operatorname{Exl}(x) \sim x \log(x) e^x$ as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: @AntonioVargas : Thank you. But since I am not familiar with the asymptotic analysis, it is not clear to me how you obtained that asymptotic form. Can you give me some hint?

Comment: Sure, I'll try to write an answer soon.

Comment: @AntonioVargas : Well, my guess is that the major contribution to the sum is from the $n \approx x$ term, so we pick up that term and use the Stirling's approximation twice, once for the $\text{log}(x)$ and another for the $x^x$ in the denominator. But I'm not sure how I can justify this is rigorous. Am I right?

Comment: I would agree with that :). After using Stirling's formula I compared the sum to an integral to derive the asymptotic.

Comment: @Antonio Vargas : I'm sorry to bother, but can we predict its behavior as $x \to -\infty$ ? Equivalently, what is the behavior of $\text{Cxl}(x)$ as $x \to \infty$ ? My guess is $\text{Exl}(x) \to -x \log (x) e^{-x}$ but numerical calculation says otherwise...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *I suspect there's a well defined special function related to this series. Is it so ?*

Not really. Basically, $\text{Exl}(x)=-F'(1),$ where $F(k)=\displaystyle\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{x^n}{n!^k}~.~$ The only known values

of *F* are $F(0)=\dfrac1{1-x},~F(1)=e^x,$ and $F(2)=I_0\big(2\sqrt x\big).$ See [Bessel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) for more

[information](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196401). Neither the function *F*, let alone its derivative, *F'*, have ever been studied for

general values of the argument *k*. Alternately, we can use [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation), but

neither $\displaystyle\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{x^n}{n!}\cdot\ln n$ nor $\displaystyle\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{x^n}{n!}\cdot n^k$ are expressible in terms of any known functions, be

they special or elementary. Well, that's not exactly true; the latter series yields the values

of [Bell numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number) for $x=1:$ see [Dobinski's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dobinski's_formula) for more [information](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614786).

Comment: There should be a [hypergeometric function answer](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/) for $\sum_{n\ge 0} n!^{-3}=\,_0\text F_2(1,1,1)$ which may imply a closed form for the other series. Also what is $\text{Exl}(x)$ here?

Comment: @TymaGaidash: $~\text{Exl}(x)~$ is the first expression on the main post.